# How does pyechonest (Echo Nest python library) collect data about current artists locally?

Tags: python, echonest

I installed the pyechonest module to do some fun music analysis and I was wondering how does pyechonest return current data on artists? Does it access a database hosted online every time I run a python script on my machine?

Comment: pyechonest is an api wrapper for [echonest.com](http://the.echonest.com/) and yes it makes calls to an online database for everything. It requires an API key to work.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by the function `pyechonest.artist.search`

I will provide you a sample code from the documentation.

> from pyechonest import artist
>
> results = artist.search(description=['synthpop'], buckets=['id:7digital', 'id:musicbrainz'], results=5)
>
> for something in results: //the rest of your code

More details can be found [here](http://www.nullege.com/codes/search/pyechonest.artist.search)

Comment: oh sorry my question was unclear. I was just wondering conceptually how the library works. Like how often is the data updated? Does it contact online servers every time it is run locally? Thanks for your answer though

Comment: I was also wondering how they process data like time_signature confidence to a certain value... does anyone know?